# How to fix sudo: setreuid(ROOT_UID, user_uid): Operation not permitted error?

Tags: sudo, authentication, ldap

I am using LDAP authentication on my Ubuntu 11.10 server. I installed libpam-ldap, and configured things accordingly. It works great, except that I get this error every once in a while when I try to sudo:

```
sudo: setreuid(ROOT_UID, user_uid): Operation not permitted
```

I know I have sudoers set up correctly, since it works most of the time. It's not just my log in either, others have the same problem when I have it. When this error is occurring, I can't ssh in with my regular system user at all. When I sign in directly, I can't get any gnome-terminal to start.

Once I restart the server, the problem goes away. 'Course, that's not a solution, if it was a prod server, I'd be in trouble.

How do I fix this?

Edit 3/1/12: I just figured out that if stop and start the nscd service, the problem goes away.

```
service nscd stop
service nscd start
```

Not much of a solution since I have to be logged into the server directly, not via ssh.

Comment: I did find this: http://us.generation-nt.com/answer/bug-545414-sudo-ldap-sudo-fails-sudo-setreuid-root-uid-user-uid-operation-not-permitted-ldap-users-help-201369432.html And I have tried using libnss-ldapd. It didn't work very well. Though I intend to try again.

Comment: I tried libnss-ldapd, but I couldn't get it to let me authenticate via ldap. I probably missed some part of the configuration, but I can't figure out what. 

So, what other solutions are there?

Comment: The libnss-ldapd libraries worked for me.  I purged libnss-ldap and libpam-ldap and installed libnss-ldapd and libpam-ldapd.

Comment: libnss-ldapd works but libpam-ldap breaks vsftpd :( It can be made to work by manually configuring /etc/pam.d/vsftpd and commenting out @include common-auth and put info in manually.  What a pain!

Comment: So, does it break vsftpd for regular system accounts, or just LDAP accounts?

I really need to find some time to test libnss again. I'm positive it's the solution, but I keep missing some key configuration somewhere when I try it...

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what are you using as your binddn in /etc/ldap.conf?  Are you binding anonymously?

Comment: It can break vsftpd for all users. The problem lies somewhere in the way it integrates in /etc/pam.d/common-auth. To fix it, edit /etc/pam.d/vsftpd and comment out @include common-auth and add the lines from common-auth manually:`auth [success=2 default=ignore] pam_unix.so nullok_secure` `auth [success=1 default=ignore] pam_ldap.so minimum_uid=1000 use_first_pass` `auth requisite pam_deny.so` or whatever is appropriate for your configuration. My common-auth has samba sync and that is what was causing problems for vsftpd.
auth    required                        pam_permit.so

Comment: I was using a bind user that used to work perfectly on CentOS 5.something.

Comment: Setting up libpam-ldap and libnss-ldap with anonymous auth works for me with the default acls for ldap.  This apparently has something to do with the bind user. Is your binddn also your rootdn? Previously, I used a proxy as that seemed more secure.

Comment: Anon bind is not allowed on our servers. The binddn is a user created with the appropriate permissions. Read only, if I am right, it was actually created by the previous admin...

Comment: Apparently, this is a bug (perhaps holy war) in the way OpenLDAP uses gnuTLS.  See [Ubuntu Bug #423252](https://bugs.launchpad.net/debian/+source/sudo/+bug/423252/), [Debian Bug #545414](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=545414), [Debian Bug #566351](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=566351), and [Debian Bug #579647](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=579647).  These issues are evidently not seen when OpenLDAP is compiled against OpenSSL which is probably why the issue is not seen in CentOS.

Comment: This is why anon bind works, and as this is an old bug, probably why Ubuntu defaults this way.  The work around is to use libnss-ldapd; however, this may also fail when using libgcrypt/gnuTLS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/debian/+source/sudo/+bug/423252/) that was introduced when Debian (and therefore Ubuntu) switched from using **OpenSSL** to **GnuTLS** with **OpenLDAP** because of the licensing difficulties with **OpenSSL**.  The problem is with the way `libgcrypt` (the current crypto backend for **GnuTLS**) initializes.  The problem has been around since **Ubuntu 9.10** and hasn't really been addressed because upstream **GnuTLS** is switching from `libgcrypt` (which evidently has other problems as well) to [libnettle](http://www.lysator.liu.se/~nisse/nettle/http://www.lysator.liu.se/~nisse/nettle/). Until this change makes it downstream, there are three possible work arounds, all of which are enumerated in the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/debian/+source/sudo/+bug/423252/) above.

1. **Compile** `libgnutls26` from source to **use** `libnettle` instead of `libgcrypt`
2. **Compile** `libldap` from source to **use** `openssl` instead of `gnutls26`
3. **Use** `libnss-ldapd` instead of `libnss-ldap`. This has several variations.  First use `libpam-ldap` which pulls in `libnns-ldap` as a dependency which makes configuration complicated. And second, use `libpam-ldapd` which is not complete.  It especially lacks all the **pam_*** configurations which allow limiting subsets of users. In order to overcome this deficiency you could use the nssov overlay with slapd, but this is not included in slapd with Ubuntu (So you would need to compile from source). `libpam-ldapd` uses the `nslcd` daemon to handle the ldap lookups; it therefore uses `/etc/nslcd.conf`
   instead of `/etc/ldap` for configuration.  Of particular note, you could use the `pam_authz_search` to restrict authorization. See `man nslcd.conf` for details. There is also a pretty good howto [here](http://arthurdejong.org/nss-pam-ldapd/setup), and [here](http://www.ossramblings.com/openldap-authentication-with-tls-ssl) if you need to configure startTLS.

**UPDATE:** As of 5/29/2012 a bug fix was available in the proposed repository for **Lucid**, **Natty**, and **Oneiric**. This fixed the issues with LDAP logins; however, as of 9/6/2012 this new patch has been shown to break other packages[1](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libgcrypt11/+bug/1013798), and has been removed. Also, as documented in [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnutls26/+bug/926350/), the workaround using nscd, no longer works at all. This is an unfortunate regression, and worse, the problem isn't really fixed in **Precise** and **Quantal**. Ultimately, the only real fix is to ditch `libgcrypt11` in favor `libnettle4`. The newer `libgnutls28` in [Precise](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libgnutls28) and [Quantal](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/libgnutls28) already do this, but `libldap` still uses `libgnutls26`.

The instructions to **compile** `libgnutls26` from **source** are explained in comments [22](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnutls26/+bug/926350/comments/22), [23](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnutls26/+bug/926350/comments/23), and [24](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnutls26/+bug/926350/comments/24) in [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnutls26/+bug/926350). But the instructions seem to only work for **Precise**.

Comment: So, I was about to try setting this up again on a 12.04 test server, but from your update, I'd have to compile libgnutls26. Since I don't have enough users that LDAP auth is essential, I think I'll not use LDAP auth for the foreseeable future. Thanks for your help, Chris, especially the updates. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

An insecure measure: disable SSL